# Preventing jfx packager's secondary launcher from triggering UAC/elevated privilege in Windows

Tags: java, windows, maven, uac, privileges

I am working on a JavaFX app that I'd like it to automatically update. I am using the [JavaFX Maven Plugin](https://github.com/javafx-maven-plugin/javafx-maven-plugin) and building a native package (the JavaFX Maven plugin uses javapackager) for each OS: Linux, Windows and OSX. I am using the latest JDK 8u74 because it has the "secondary launchers" feature, this should make it possible to have more than one native launcher bundled in my package. I added the two launchers in the pom.xml with:

```
        <groupId>com.zenjava</groupId>
        <artifactId>javafx-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>8.2.0</version>
        <configuration>
            <mainClass>MainApp</mainClass>
            <appName>MainApp</appName>
            <verbose>true</verbose>
            <jfxMainAppJarName>application.jar</jfxMainAppJarName>
            <secondaryLaunchers>
                <launcher>
                    <appName>AnotherApp</appName>
                    <mainClass>AnotherApp</mainClass>
                </launcher>
            </secondaryLaunchers>
        </configuration>
```

So, on Windows, after users install this JavaFX app, there are two launchers under path 
  **\User\userName\AppData\Local\ourApp**
, bundled with the same JVM.  Let's call the first launcher MainApp and the second one AnotherApp.

Now the problem is: On Windows, somehow the AnotherApp will require UAC (Admin privileges) while the MainApp doesn't.

Obviously, I ask the app to be installed in ...\AppData\Local is because I do not want it to trigger the elevated privilege. I also looked in here: http://mark.koli.ch/uac-prompt-from-java-createprocess-error740-the-requested-operation-requires-elevation, but it doesn't solve the problem.

So my questions are: When there are two launchers, why does the secondary launcher need the elevated privileges? How can I avoid this?

Comment: This is a really interesting puzzle and challenging problem, if you get an answer, please also tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally figured out this wired problem.

The issue is about the appName. In my code, I was actually using `<appName>Updater</appName>` for my second launcher. In Windows, it seems they programmed the OS so that any .exe with word "update" will trigger the UAC.

So the solution is: change the appName to something else...